# JQuery plugin is breaking the behavior of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, drop-down-menu

I have a Search Form on a web page that works successfully, where when a Category is chosen the sub-category drop-down populates successfully after the Category is chosen, that uses this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[name='channel']").change(function() {
            var channel_id = $(this).val();

            console.log(channel_id);

            $("select[name='sub_category']").html("<option value='All'>Sub Category</option>");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax.php",
                data: "channel_id=" + channel_id,
                dataType: 'json',
                statusCode: {
                    200: function(data) {
                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $("select[name='sub_category']").append("<option value='" + data[i]["sub_channel_id"] + "'>" + data[i]["sub_channel_name"] + "</option>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, when a jquery plug-in is added in, the Search Form works except the sub-category drop-down doesn't populate successfully after a Category is chosen,
The jQuery script uses this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select.ui-select").selectWidget({
            change: function(changes) {
                return changes;
            },
            effect: "slide",
            keyControl: true,
            speed: 200,
            scrollHeight: 250
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is where I am getting stuck. Any ideas on how  I could fix this?

Comment: Does this plugin changes the dom structure?

Comment: you should be using the plugin api to make changes.... or you will need to reinitialize plugin if you change the element yourself

Comment: @charlietfl I am not sure what you mean but here is the plugin:http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Custom-Select-Dropdown-List-Plugin-For-jQuery-jQuery-UI.html